# Why would bytes data decoded to string unable to parse with Element tree?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am trying to parse the XML data received from a socket after decoding bytes to 'utf-8' as string and create an Element using ET. This is the part of code in the class. (Using Python. Element tree is imported as ET)

```
data = self.sock.recv(1024)
print(data)  #-------------->(This returns: b'\x02<V_ConnectionStatus><Version>0.4.0</Version><ServerId>Simulator</ServerId><Status>ConnectionAccepted</Status></V_ConnectionStatus>\x03'

os_encoding = locale.getpreferredencoding()
print(os_encoding)    # -------------------> To know what is returned(This returns cp1252)
print(data.decode("utf-8"))  #-------------->(This returns: <V_ConnectionStatus><Version>0.4.0</Version><ServerId>Simulator</ServerId><Status>ConnectionAccepted</Status></V_ConnectionStatus>)

ULSCdata= data.decode('utf-8') 
#ULSCdata= data.decode('cp1252')
print(type(ULSCdata))  #-------------->(This returns:<class 'str'> )

try:
    root = ET.fromstring(ULSCdata)   # **everything except this line works**
    print(root.tag)
except:
    print('unable to parse your data')
```

All time I execute, except print statement execute.
Any eye opener?

Comment: try `except Exception as e:` and print `e`

Comment: I received this: 'not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0'

Comment: add `print(ULSCdata)` before you call `ET.fromstring(ULSCdata)`. Share the output

Comment: print(ULSCdata) outputs: <V_ConnectionStatus><Version>0.4.0</Version><ServerId>Simulator</ServerId><Status>ConnectionAccepted</Status></V_ConnectionStatus>

Comment: This looks like a valid xml so I guess there is something missing. if you pass `<V_ConnectionStatus><Version>0.4.0</Version><ServerId>Simulator</ServerId><Status>ConnectionAccepted</Status></V_ConnectionStatus>` to ElementTree - it should work.

Comment: It cannot parse the **first** character - `\x02`... `ET.fromstring(b'\x02'.decode('cp1252'))` produces  `xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0`

Comment: @wwii according to OP, there is no \x02 in the string...

Comment: there are a number of probable duplicate if you search with `python xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0 site:stackoverflow.com` - if/when you hand one that answers your question let us know and we will mark yours as a duplicate.

Comment: @balderman in the question's example the second line - `print(data)  #---...` says that there is.

Comment: @wwii see comment number 5

Comment: @wwii Commenting that line of code to avoid confusion

Comment: @balderman Yes, hardcoding the entire string instead of ULSCdata works fine(which I cannot do as This is a socket response), but not sure why string variable gives out error.

Comment: I was thinking this is an encoding issue, But not sure if that is anything ET.fromstring.

Comment: What do you get with `[hex(c) for c in data]`?

Comment: Found  the reason, posting it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the issue. I must have added [1:-1] after decoding utf-8

```
ULSCdata= data.decode('utf-8')[1:-1]
```